# How to automate paging on GridView using Timer from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, gridview

I have a gridview on my page. I want the page to show me next 10 records after every 10 seconds. i.e. automated paging.

I have implemented manual paging on Gridview. How can I do this using Client Side event triggering

Comment: Do you use updatepanel ? or you wish to reload the page ?

Comment: @Aristos: Yes, I am using Update Panel. Although I would be looking towards it working with Js rather than server side timer

Answer (score 0):

I think this can do the work, just need some checks and defind the MaxPages that its easy

```
var CurrentPage = 1;
setInterval( function()
 {
  CurrentPage++;
  if(CurrentPage > MaxPages)
   CurrentPage = 1;

  __doPostBack('<%=MyGrid.UniqueID%>','Page$'+ CurrentPage );
 },10000);
```